# AWSAPIGatewayClient always results in unauthorised

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

When using the amazon generated code for AWSAPIGatewayClient I always get

> message = Unauthorized;

as a response.

What could be the cause of this?

**AppDelegate**

```
AWSCognitoIdentityUserPool *pool = [AWSCognitoIdentityUserPool CognitoIdentityUserPoolForKey:@"UserPool"];
AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider *credentialsProvider = [[AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider alloc] initWithRegionType:AWSRegionUSEast1
                                                                                                identityPoolId:CognitoPoolId
                                                                                       identityProviderManager:pool];

AWSServiceConfiguration *serviceConfiguration = [[AWSServiceConfiguration alloc] initWithRegion:CognitoIdentityUserPoolRegion
                                                                            credentialsProvider:credentialsProvider];
AWSServiceManager.defaultServiceManager.defaultServiceConfiguration = serviceConfiguration;

AWSCognitoIdentityUserPoolConfiguration *configuration = [[AWSCognitoIdentityUserPoolConfiguration alloc] initWithClientId:CognitoIdentityUserPoolAppClientId
                                                                                                              clientSecret:CognitoIdentityUserPoolAppClientSecret
                                                                                                                    poolId:CognitoIdentityUserPoolId];
[AWSCognitoIdentityUserPool registerCognitoIdentityUserPoolWithConfiguration:serviceConfiguration
                                                       userPoolConfiguration:configuration
                                                                      forKey:@"UserPool"];
```

**ViewController**

```
[[[AWSPrjctRtClient defaultClient] suggestionsGet] continueWithBlock:^id _Nullable(AWSTask * _Nonnull task) {

        NSLog(@"%@", task.error);
        return nil;
}];
```

**Results in**

```
2017-04-07 16:02:24.386 xxxx[38051:1025018] Error Domain=com.amazonaws.AWSAPIGatewayErrorDomain Code=1 "(null)" UserInfo={HTTPBody={
message = Unauthorized;
```

Comment: does ur identity pool have unauth access? also, does your API allow unauth access?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The response looks like your API Gateway resource is configured to use Cognito user pools for authorization, but your code actually uses Cognito Federated Identities. In turn, Federated Identities requires API Gateway to use AWS_IAM authorizers, using IAM roles to manage access to your resources.

I would suggest you go through the following steps:

1. Follow [this guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-integrating-user-pools-with-identity-pools.html). Basically, within Cognito Federated Identities, configure an Identity Pool to use your User Pool as (one of) its Authentication provider(s). (You may have already done this)
2. Check the Authorization of your API Gateway resource(s) under Method Requests/Settings/Authorization. Set it to AWS_IAM. Don't forget to redeploy the newly configured API, and export a new SDK.
3. Your Identity Pool will require two IAM roles, for both unauthenticated and authenticated access to AWS services. You will have to add a policy to your role(s) to specify access to your AWS services, in this case you will need to grant `"execute-api:Invoke"` access to (presumably only) your authenticated role. I recommend using the policy generator for this, and make sure you get set the ARN for the policy to be only for the resource(s) you want to grant access to, otherwise all of your API Gateway resources may be accessed.
4. As for configuration on the iOS SDK side, make sure you use the code from the guide (shown below), it seems yours is slightly different. I have found that getting this wrong can induce a whole range of confusing errors that could have you look in all sorts of wrong directions for a solution.

**Add to AppDelegate**

```
AWSServiceConfiguration *serviceConfiguration = [[AWSServiceConfiguration alloc] initWithRegion:AWSRegionUSEast1
                                                                            credentialsProvider:nil];
AWSCognitoIdentityUserPoolConfiguration *userPoolConfiguration = [[AWSCognitoIdentityUserPoolConfiguration alloc] initWithClientId:@"YOUR_CLIENT_ID"
                                                                                                                      clientSecret:@"YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET"
                                                                                                                            poolId:@"YOUR_USER_POOL_ID"];
[AWSCognitoIdentityUserPool registerCognitoIdentityUserPoolWithConfiguration:serviceConfiguration
                                                       userPoolConfiguration:userPoolConfiguration forKey:@"UserPool"];
AWSCognitoIdentityUserPool *pool = [AWSCognitoIdentityUserPool CognitoIdentityUserPoolForKey:@"UserPool"];
AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider *credentialsProvider = [[AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider alloc]
                                                      initWithRegionType:AWSRegionUSEast1
                                                      identityPoolId:@"YOUR_IDENTITY_POOL_ID"
                                                      identityProviderManager:pool];
```

One important addition though! I've found this particularly confusing at first, but in the above code you initialize an `AWSServiceConfiguration` with `credentialsProvider` set to `nil` in order to register your `AWSCognitoIdentityUserPool`. However, you will need to initialize a new `AWSServiceConfiguration` that references your credentialsProvider to assign to your `AWSServiceManager.defaultServiceManager.defaultServiceConfiguration`. Like so:

```
AWSServiceManager.defaultServiceManager.defaultServiceConfiguration = [[AWSServiceConfiguration alloc] initWithRegion:CognitoUserPoolRegion
                                                                                                  credentialsProvider:credentialsProvider];
```

The above described steps ultimately led me to successfully integrating Cognito User Pools with Federated Identities to allow access to API Gateway resources. The process involved some confusion about what services do what exactly, and piecing together pieces of code from different guides. I hope this helps!

Note that you can also probably do without Federated Identities and leave your API to be authorized using the User Pool directly. But I haven't been successful in that approach. Also, Federated Identities will allow you to add other authorizers at a later stage if you please to do so.

Comment: getting an below error on this code.

Message = "User: arn:aws:sts::XXXX85095:assumed-role/XXXXXX_unauth_MOBILEHUB_XXXX039892/CognitoIdentityCredentials 
is not authorized to perform: execute-api:Invoke on resource: arn:aws:execute-api:ap-southeast-1:********5095:XXXXu7mj
/Dev/POST/XXXXX with an explicit deny";

Comment: @GautamSareriya 
Did u find the solution?